# What type of glass is used in oven glass doors?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I understand that the glass used in convection oven door must be 
able to withstand high heat.

[image]

But what should be the exact specification if I am thinking of replacing 
my broken oven door and replacements are not available and I need to 
ask the help of local glass sellers?

Comment: Most likely simple tempered glass.

Answer (score 1):

Ovens in the kitchen are not suppose to heat above 450°F. Any type of glass can handle that temperature, if the change in temperature is not too fast. For safety, I would think that tempered glass is used on the ovens.